# How to create asynchronous tasks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, task, asynchronous-javascript

How to do asynchronous tasks like this:

I want to have two tasks: One would print "foo" after 1 second, and the other one would print "bar" after 2 seconds.
I want them to start at the same time, and run asynchronously.

Here's an example of this in python:

```
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 2 seconds.)
    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

How do I do something like this in JavaScript? Do I use promises? I don't know how they work. I'm "new" to javascript

Comment: In JS you can use `async` and `await` too, in a very similar manner as you do above.

Comment: and how do i create a task?

Comment: setTimeout() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout 

In JavaScript you have the Event Loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

By calling a Function with setTimeout(), you're adding it to the Queue. The commands in the queue execute sequentially in the order they are added, never synchronously. I'm not sure how JS Engines deal with the timeout internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `then` method of js promises.

```js
function timeout(time_ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time_ms));
}


function main() {
  timeout(1000).then(() => console.log("hello"))
  timeout(2000).then(() => console.log("world"))

  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  console.log(`started at ${n}`)

}

main()
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted to achieve

Comment: P.S. `Promise().then` is a way of `async` programming in javascript

Comment: works as well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Hi!

You can do it like this:

```js
async function hello() {
  setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)
  console.log("hello")
}

async function world() {
  setTimeout(() => {}, 2000)
  console.log("world")
}

async function main() {
  await hello()
  await world()
}

main()
```

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: both end right after starting the program

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out:

```js
async function foo() {
    return setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("foo")
        }, 1000);
}

async function bar() {
    return setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("bar")
        }, 1500);
}   

foo()
bar()
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `async` in your function declarations, since you're not `await`ing anything

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you not to use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) but [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if you want to be good at JavaScript.

Promise is an expression that has a strong algebraic structure, and async-await, on the other hand, they are statements that has complicated rules.

Comment: Async/Await uses promises under the hood. In most cases it's better to use async/await since it's easier to reason about, but there are a few cases where promises are the better choice